# Ошибка парсинга патронов в Yandex.Tank

Tags: яндекс-танк

Запускаю Яндекс.Танк со следующими данными:

**ammo.txt:**

```
191
POST /check_spelling? HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: yandex-tank/1.1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Length:18
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: Close

text=Test sentence
```

**load.ini:**

```
[phantom]
address=127.0.0.1:3000
rps_schedule=line(1, 100, 1)
```

В результате получаю следующую ошибку:

```
12:43:18 INFO: Setting ammo_type 'uri' because ammo is not started 

with digit and you did not specify ammo format
12:43:18 INFO: Loading ammo from 'load.ini' using URI format.
12:43:18 INFO: Using UriReader ammo reader
12:43:18 INFO: Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/core/consoleworker.py", line 263, in perform_test
    self.core.plugins_prepare_test()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/core/tankcore.py", line 303, in plugins_prepare_test
    plugin.prepare_test()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/plugins/Phantom/plugin.py", line 112, in prepare_test
    self.config = self.phantom.compose_config()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/plugins/Phantom/PhantomUtils.py", line 92, in compose_config
    streams_config += stream.compose_config()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/plugins/Phantom/PhantomUtils.py", line 263, in compose_config
    self.stepper_wrapper.prepare_stepper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/stepper/main.py", line 206, in prepare_stepper
    self.__make_stpd_file()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/stepper/main.py", line 296, in __make_stpd_file
    stepper.write(os)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/stepper/main.py", line 61, in write
    for missile in self.ammo:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/stepper/format.py", line 15, in <genexpr>
    return ("%s %s %s\n%s\n" % (len(missile), timestamp, marker, missile) for timestamp, marker, missile in self.af)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/stepper/main.py", line 48, in <genexpr>
    (timestamp, marker or self.marker(missile), missile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/stepper/main.py", line 41, in <genexpr>
    ammo_stream = (ammo for ammo in (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/stepper/main.py", line 42, in <genexpr>
    (missile, marker or self.marker(missile))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/stepper/missile.py", line 258, in __iter__
    _parse_header(line.strip('\r\n[]\t ')))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandextank/stepper/missile.py", line 235, in _parse_header
    return dict([(h.strip() for h in header.split(':', 1))])
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

12:43:18 ERROR: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Выглядит так, как будто Яндекс.Танк не может распарсить `ammo.txt`. Можете подсказать, в чем проблема?

Comment: Вопрос нужно задавать на русском.

Comment: Я думаю, вряди ли кто-нибудь знает здесь про Яндекс.Танк. Предлагаю обратиться к разработчикам Танка в [чате](https://gitter.im/yandex/yandex-tank), а как разберетесь, ответ написать здесь.

Comment: @MichaelPak Надо что бы r2d2 вопрос увидел, он один из разработчиков танка и отвечает тут на вопросы

Comment: @Mike я в свое время разбирался с танком, задал вопрос туда. Ответили меньше, чем через пол дня.

Answer (score 1):

Пока все выглядит так, будто танк был запущен без указания файла с запросами.

После запуска, танк создает папку с артефактами, в ней должен быть файл `lunapark_*.lock`, это итоговый "снимок" параметров запуска танка. Что в нем записано в опции ammofile?
Если был указан ammo.txt, то должно быть что-то вроде `ammofile = ammo.txt`

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверьте, что файл с патронами начинается с цифры, именно так (проверяя, что первый символ -- это цифра) танк понимает, что это `.stpd`
2. Можете зафорсить формат `stpd`:

   ammo_type = phantom